# iframe not loading its source on specific kind of pages: XML and Chrome pages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome Extension, in order to display to my user some information, I create and add an IFrame to the DOM of the page.

The Iframe contains a template defined in my extension.

No problem so far with this in most pages, except when I try to open my extension on specific pages:

- XML document such as RSS Feeds ==> **I really need to solve this**.
- Specific Chrome pages ==>  I don't really care about this use case.

---

I create and manage the iframe in the following way when the user open my extension:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id  = "my_awesome_iframe";

// Then I specify the source: I ask chrome to look for it. 
// I have checked the correct URL is returned. No problem so far here.
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("templates/page.html');

// Here the problems start: 
// with a normal page: No problem
// with an XML document: I have the error: "style is undefined, can't set cssText"
iframe.style.cssText = 'height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;';

// I can solve this doing the following:
iframe.setAttribute("style", 'height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;');

// And finally
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

But now, that everything is set properly. And whenever I am in one of the cases cited above, the src url is just **not loaded**. I have the iframe element inside the DOM but it's just empty.

Just to check, I tried the following:

```
document.getElementById("my_awesome_iframe").contentWindow

// As expected, I obtain the following only when the iframe refuses to load.
>> undefined
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

I really need to be able to load my extension when the user is on an XML file such an RSS Feed. It's one of the main point of my extension.

---

Additional Information:

My extension is compatible with Firefox with the exact same implementation. The behavior is  a bit different. When the XML document is an RSS feed I can open mmy extension, when it is something else: it's impossible.

Example Links:

- RSS Feed: https://www.feedcrunch.io/@dataradar/rss/ (works only with FF)
- XML Document: http://www.httrack.com/httrack.xml (fail on FF and Chrome)

**There must be some XMLViewer-specific thing, but I don't know where to look for...**

Comment: Try `iframe = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'iframe')` and `iframe.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', '/* your CSS here */')`

Comment: @wOxxOm: You rock! That worked. I can't flag your awswer as good. Could you copy/paste it as a normal answer ;)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML documents require namespace for the elements you create:

```
var iframe = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'iframe');
```

and the attributes should be set like this:

```
iframe.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', '/* your CSS here */');
```